# IBM Worklight / Zxing- Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined barcodescanner.js:10

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ibm-mobilefirst, zxing

I'm using worklight and zxing for my qr reader mobile app project. My problem is, i got this error after I run this app in my google chrome.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined barcodescanner.js:10
```

Error line 10 in barcodescanner.js

```
var exec = require("cordova/exec");
```

Even I included cordova file into index.html, the error message still occuring.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>index</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footer.css">
            <!-- require.js:  data-main attribute tells require.js to load
             js/main.js after require.js loads. -->

             <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
             <script src="js/vendor/phoneGap/cordova-1.6.0.js"></script>
             <script src="js/vendor/phoneGap/barcodescanner.js"></script>
             <script data-main="js/main" src="js/vendor/require/require.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body>

        </body>
</html>
```

Check my repo here: https://github.com/datomnurdin/worklight-mobile

Comment: nothing happens. I already read the worklight documentation but not helping. http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/06_03_iOS_-_Adding_native_functionality_to_hybrid_application_with_Apache_Cordova_plugin.pdf

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens? What do you see in the Xcode Console? No logs? Provide your project.

Comment: before that, I test sample code from developerworks, I got permission denied when build the project in xcode.

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/iOSApacheCordovaPluginProject.zip

Comment: my project included in question

Comment: My Mac crashed. I'll try when it is working again.

Comment: sure2. take your time @IdanAdar. I'm really appreciate you helping me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The barcode scanner code will **not** work outside the supported environments (iOS devices and Android devices, according to the plugin page).

Wrap environment specific code like the one inside barcodescanner.js in environment check tags. For example:

```
if (WL.Client.getEnvironment() === "android") {
   //barcodescanner.js and other code that should only run on android
}
```

Also, try replacing in barcodescanner.js:

`var exec = require("cordova/exec")`

with:

`var exec = cordova.exec`

or:

Try [an older version of the plugin like 0.7.2](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/blob/0.7.2/www/barcodescanner.js), notice the use of `cordova.define` to provide the `require` function, [instead of expecting the `require` global function to magically exist](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/blob/1.0.1/www/barcodescanner.js).

Comment: can I use that older vesion of the plugin for android platform

Comment: I resolved the issue.But I am still getting cannot read property barcodeScanner of undefined property.